# Trying to setup IP addresses on my network

Tags: networking, ip, ping, gateway

[image: my network]
Here's my schema. I'm trying to set up IP addresses to be able to PING from the first floor ( etage 1 ) to the second ( etage 2).

I tried setting up an IP address 192.168.233.2/24 with the gateway 192.168.233.1 to PC D , and 192.168.233.3/24 with the gateway 192.168.233.1 but I'm not able to PING.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ocFVw.png)

Comment: You don't need a gateway to ping within the same subnet. What's the error message you get?

Comment: i configured pcC with the address 192.168.233.2 and pcD with the address 192.168.233.3 and i set the gatweway 192.168.233.1 ( but i didn't specifiy it anywhere) and i can"t ping from pcD to pcC ( i get the message host unreachable )

Comment: Is the switch between floor 1 and floor 2 only a switch? That is, are you sure it doesn't do any layer 3 operations?

Comment: i set it as a l3 switch to be able to assign an ip address to the interfaces , what i want is to set the appropriate ip addresses to the drawing to be able to ping from the first floor to the second , is there any way you can edit the schema and write the appropriate ip addresses , thank you

Answer (score 1):

Your diagram does not show IP addresses, so we can't tell how you have things configured.  Here's one way you might do things:

1. Interfaces e0/0, e0/1, e0/2 and e0/3 should all be in the same VLAN.
   They should not be L3 interfaces.
2. The VLAN interface (L3) will have the address 192.168.233.1
3. You need a default route on the switch with the next hop of the
   Firewall (port 2)
4. The firewall needs a route to the 192.168.223.0/24 network with the
   next hop of the switch.

Comment: and by the way i can't ping the gateway ( i choose the switch  interface as a gateway to the pc it is linked to ) thank you

Comment: Your pc addresses must be in the same subnet as the interface on the core switch. The core switch interface is the default gateway for the PCs. You need that configured.

Comment: thank you for your response ; how can i add default route on the switch with the next hop of the Firewall  and a route to the 192.168.223.0/24 network with the next hop of the switch for the firewall ? thank you

Comment: i put all the interfaces in the same vlan with the address 192.168.214.40 and the firewall with the address 192.168.233.41 , is it okay ?

Comment: i edited the diagram , please check it, also how can i configure the rest of the devices ( core switch ( switch federateur ) and the rest , thank you

Comment: Your addressing scheme seems OK for a prototype.  You need static routes on the core switch and firewall.

Comment: i edited once again , does it seems okay , for the switch access , e0/2 , e1/0, e0/0 , e1/1 ,e0/3 and  e0/1 are in the same vlan 

same thing for the switch in the dmz , e0/2 , e0/1 and e0/0 are in the same vlan   , how can i configure static routes on the core switch and the firewall ?

Comment: the switch in the dmz is an l2 switch , should i affect ip addresses to its interface ?

Comment: L2 switches only have IPs for management.  Otherwise, they don't care about IPs.

Comment: okay thank you Ron , i edited the diagram once again , does it seems okay , for the switch access , e0/2 , e1/0, e0/0 , e1/1 ,e0/3 and e0/1 are in the same vlan same thing for the switch in the dmz , e0/2 , e0/1 and e0/0 are in the same vlan , how can i configure static routes on the core switch and the firewall ?

Comment: I don't know what kind of devices you have.

Comment: i'm working on eve-ng ,it's not specified, i'm guessing its cisco , are the ip addresses and the subnet adresses right ?

Comment: how can i configure static routes on the core switch and the firewall ?

Comment: For Cisco devices the command is `ip route <subnet> <mask> <next-hop>` For example, `0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 192.168.215.47`.